# weather app infomation in ios

Tags: ios, weather-api

Can we able to get information from weather app like temperature and other stuff programmatically. Do we have any framework in `IOS` or should we use apis from `Google` or `Yahoo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing is built into the iOS SDK directly, if that's what you are asking.

You'll either need to use API's from Google or Yahoo or Weather Underground (wunderground.com), or you might be able to use *third party* frameworks that folks have made available publicly or commercially.

If it helps you, [here is a sample GitHub project that uses Wunderground API's](https://github.com/robertmryan/ios-wunderground-demo).

Comment: Ok. I will check out the links.

Answer (score 1):

I also had a similar query. I found the OpenWeatherMap API to be very helpful. I wrote a simple wrapper for it so that you can manipulate weather data directly using dot notation.
http://jonathanfield.me/objective-c-openweathermap-api-wrapper/

Answer (score 0):

I created sample **iOS Weather app** using- Swift,Protocaol oriented programming(POP), Codable, OpenWeatherMap Api, MVVM design pattern with Unit Test.

https://github.com/deepakiosdev/WeatherApp/tree/master

May be it will helpful.